# calling a post method

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I'm unable to call post method from android app
when i call the following url from chorome browser it work ok

> http://172.16.2.113/api/DigitechProductsAC/PostService?ctcCompany=test&name=test&mobile=test1&description=test2&address=test3&productCompany=test4&extra1=asdf&extra2=3434

and i got the following response

> Request URL: http://172.16.2.113/api/DigitechProductsAC/PostService?ctcCompany=test&name=test&mobile=test1&description=test2&address=test3&productCompany=test4&extra1=asdf&extra2=3434
>   Request Method: POST
>   Response Time: 6.689 seconds
>   Response Status: 200 - OK

but from android it's not working .. my current android code is :

```
String url1= "http://172.16.2.113/api/DigitechProductsAC/PostService";
            String  data= "ctcCompany=test&name=test&mobile=test1&description=test2&address=test3&productCompany=test4&extra1=asdf&extra2=zzz";

        String response = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String urlParam = data;
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT","Mozilla/5.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE","en-US,en;0.5");

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(urlParam);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            int responseCode= connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode==200)

         return  "OK";
            else
                return "";
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

It is not reaching the server !!

Comment: Please extend your question. What is it's not working? Does it reach the server? Does it throw an error?

Comment: It is not reaching the server

Comment: 1: Do you run this code asynchronous inside an `AsyncTask`. 2: Did you debug this code, I mean where it stops, what is the response status code, response error, or what exception is thrown?